# Horizontal Line Styling on Each Side of Titles

Tags: html, css, wordpress, styling

I am working on a Wordpress blog, and I am trying to figure out how to add horizontal lines on each side of some of my titles like the ones in this link:

http://falive.jegtheme.com/?slider=highlightslider&homelayout=normal&homesidebar=true&layout=full&header=1&sticky=true

In the blog above, titles in the sidebar, and the 'share this article' title has the desired effect that I am looking for, but can't seem to figure out how to get it. I know the basics of HTML and CSS, so this could be something that I am simply overlooking or just haven't learned yet.

Also, is there a way to take this type of styling to the next level by adding more unique types of lines (like long curly lines) through CSS?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [`:before`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before) or [:after](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after)

Example 1:

```css
h2{        
    padding: 0 20px;        
    text-align: center;
}
h2:before,
h2:after{
    content: '';    
    width: 150px;    
    height: 1px;
    margin: 0 10px;
    background: #ccc;  
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;   
}
```

```html
<h2>title</h2>
<h2>title title title</h2>
```

Example 2

```css
div{
    text-align: center;
}
h2 {
    padding: 0 20px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
}
h2:before, 
h2:after {
    content:'';    
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute; top: 50%;
    height: 1px;    
    background: #ccc;    
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
h2:before{
    right: 100%;
}
h2:after{
    left: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div>
<h2>title</h2>
<br>
<h2>title title title</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I haven't used those pseudo-celements yet, so the examples are perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Using your browser's developer tools, inspect the `span` elements containing those titles. You'll see `:before` and `:after` [CSS3 selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3A%3Abefore) in which some positional/border styling is used.

Can you use other kinds of lines? Sure -- CSS3 would allow you to use a wide variety of things, but the list is probably too long to list here on SO.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Would you be able to point me in the direction of a source that may list some of these stylings? It'll be much appreciated!